# How to run Junit tests all together?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse,I can click the test/ directory and right click "run as junit test", and all tests will be run together.

In Intellij, it seems that I have to click each individual test class and run the test per class. Is this true? I am new to Intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Run -> Edit Configuration -> Junit -> give your package Name  -> Click ok Button.

Here is the screen shots :

[image]

[image]